# Render two images to an SDL_window

Tags: sdl, c, image, interface

I want to create a menu for an SDL game, so I load an Image to an SDL_Window as the background, then I try to load the next image which will be a button but it doesn't display the button to the window, it just displays the background.

I'm a newbie so perhaps it is an obvious mistake.

Here's what I got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 1;
    SDL_Event event;

    SDL_Window* window;
    SDL_Surface* background_surface;
    SDL_Texture* background_texture;
    SDL_Renderer* background_renderer;
    SDL_Surface* button_surface;
    SDL_Texture* button_texture;
    SDL_Renderer* button_renderer;

    SDL_Rect button_pos;
    button_pos.h = 65;
    button_pos.w = 320;
    button_pos.x = 0;
    button_pos.y = 0;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "Cosmic Racing",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        320,
        568,
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL
    );
    background_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    background_surface = SDL_LoadBMP("Background.bmp");
    background_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(background_renderer, background_surface);
    SDL_RenderCopy(background_renderer, background_texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(background_renderer);

    button_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    button_surface = SDL_LoadBMP("Play.bmp");
    button_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(button_renderer, button_surface);
    SDL_RenderCopy(button_renderer, button_texture, &button_pos, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(button_renderer);

    while(a)
    {
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);
        if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            a = 0;
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyTexture(button_texture);
    SDL_FreeSurface(button_surface);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(button_renderer);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(background_texture);
    SDL_FreeSurface(background_surface);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(background_renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

BTW if you find additional mistakes please tell me. Thank you ;)

Comment: Also, if you didn't know there is a library called [SDL_image](http://libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/) which supports loading of pngs, jpegs, etc..

Comment: Oh thanks I was going to look up for that, since bmps don't support transparency. I'll search for it and what happens.

Comment: This [tutorial](http://www.willusher.io/sdl2%20tutorials/2013/08/18/lesson-3-sdl-extension-libraries/) is C++ based, but just look on how he uses the SDL_image function calls and implement them on your own. I am sure you are capable of that

Comment: Well I'll try to, it's just that I really tried to learn C++ first but just couldn't understand OOP, so I tried C and it was much easier, but I think I'm starting to get it.

Comment: oh ignore all the oop stuff, you'll never need it if you can survive in C. Use a C++ compiler (also compiles C) and code C and when you find something useful that is in c++, incorporate it! I never used any OOP in c++ yet, i just use struct's which are also in C. Please, c++ will save you from learning C-Style strings. Here is an example of creating a string in c++ (first add this `#include <string>`) `std::string string = "Hello World!"`

Comment: @saloomi2012 `c++ will save you from learning C-Style strings`, well IMO you *should* learn C style strings, before using std::string

Comment: @saloomi2012 well I think I understamd C strings correctly. Anyway thanks for your advice. Still I'll google std::string and will use it I find it easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use ONE renderer for your rendering needs. Please don't use two.

Don't use the OpenGL flag if you are not going to use it!

For the SINGLE renderer, I am assuming you want gpu rendering so replace the 0 in the last argument in `SDL_CreateRenderer()` and replace it with `SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED`.

Here is the fixed source code, Used some random images to test it and works fine, also please dont `#include <stdio.h>` when you are never using it in this code. Please don't leave those pointers unassigned! Please always `NULL` them when you initialize them to avoid issues and future bugs. Also place the `SDL_RenderCopy()` & `SDL_RenderPresent()` in the very end of your `while` loop to avoid future issues I am predicting you will have. Also added `SDL_RenderClear()` just to make the code more future proof (lol). Also in `SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, button_texture, &button_pos, NULL)` you did it wrong, it should be `SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, button_texture, NULL, &button_pos);`

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int a = 1;
SDL_Event event;

SDL_Window* window = NULL;
SDL_Surface* background_surface = NULL;
SDL_Texture* background_texture = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
SDL_Surface* button_surface = NULL;
SDL_Texture* button_texture = NULL;

SDL_Rect button_pos;
button_pos.w = 320;
button_pos.h = 65;
button_pos.x = 0;
button_pos.y = 0;

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
window = SDL_CreateWindow(
    "Cosmic Racing",
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    320,
    568,
    SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
);
renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
background_surface = SDL_LoadBMP("Background.bmp");
background_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, background_surface);

button_surface = SDL_LoadBMP("Play.bmp");
button_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, button_surface);

while(a)
{
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);
    if(event.type == SDL_QUIT)
    {
        a = 0;
    }
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, background_texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, button_texture, NULL, &button_pos);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

SDL_DestroyTexture(button_texture);
SDL_FreeSurface(button_surface);
SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
SDL_DestroyTexture(background_texture);
SDL_FreeSurface(background_surface);
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
SDL_Quit();
return 0;
}
```